# PHP: Array declaration issue

Tags: php

I want to declare about 100 arrays, like `$game1_array`, `$game2_array` ... `$game100_array` and use them in a calculation. Can I use some sort of look, going from 1 to 100 and declare these in 4 lines rather than declaring them independently?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
$game.'$i'._array = array();
}
```

Please point out the error.

Comment: it's `${'game'.$i.'_array'}` actually. But - why?

Comment: Why don't you use array of arrays instead? `$game1_array , $game2_array` is a really bad design decision

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to accomplish is a poor design decision. It's much better to create an array which holds 100 nested arrays.

It could be done with such code:

```
$games = array_fill(0, 100, array());
```

Then you can work with them like:

```
$games[42][] = 'foo'; // would append a 'foo' item into 43rd array
```

Comment: If the array is numerically indexed and you know the array size, it's probably a better idea to use splFixedArrays

Comment: @onetrickpony: indeed, but probably it would be too much for a total newbie :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    ${'game'.$i.'_array'} = array();
}

var_dump( $game2_array );
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Could upvoters comment why do you do that? I agree this answer directly answers the question, but don't you think that the major difference between SO and yahoo answers is that we can think here, and that our mission here is to teach people not just blindly give them examples of crappy code?

Comment: see, i think pointing out errors in a taken approach is as much part of "the mission" as showing a potentially better one is   ... +1 for your answer though ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
 $gameArray[$i] = array();
}
```